If two chords ( AB, CD ) intersect at P (outside the circle, Chords extended) prove that (AP)(PB) = (PC)(PD)
I could prove it when P is inside the circle, Using similarity. Then my reference book extended this proof to a point P outside the circle. If we join AD, This question becomes to prove similarity between the two triangles (as the included angle is common , SAS criterion) -
$(PA)\over(PD)$ = $(PC)\over(PB)$
But their similarity would imply that AD is parallel to BC,
Then due to the properties of a cyclic quadrilateral, Would imply that the angles formed to be 90, Thus the diagonal passes through the centre, Which may not be true.
My questions are as follows-

Where am I wrong?
What is the correct proof of the same?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance for the amazing answers!
Edit - I just realised that the sides are "inverted" in a way-
$(PA)\over(PD)$ = $(PC)\over(PB)$
Had it been -
$(PA)\over(PD)$ = $(PB)\over(PC)$
Then, AD would have been parallel to BC.

Do you want to know about this? https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/circle-intersect-secants-line.html

@Gwen thanks a lot! I understand the proof but where exactly am I going wrong though?

Ahh I get it now, The similarity doesn't imply that angle PDA is equal to angle PCA, as the sides are are inverted in the equation
